# How do put start the second line of the title exactly under the first line insted of icons

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the icon and title next together. When the title is too long, the second line starts under the icon instead of the title. I need help when the title is long and must be under the first letter, not an icon.

[image]

```
<div className="notAcceptingPatients col-med-6"\>
<h6 className="font-weight-bold text-dark "\>
<i
style={{
color: '#D14444',
fontSize: 23,
marginRight: 6,
}}
class="fa fa-info-circle"\>\</i\>

This Dental Clinic is not accepting new patients at
this time \</h6\>
<p className="notAcceptingPatients ml-2"\>
<p\>
the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\</p\>
</p\>
</div\>
```

```
CSS
.notAcceptingPatients {
 padding: 11px ;
 background: rgba(219, 88, 88, 0.1);
 border-radius: 8px;

p {
margin: 2px;
font-size: 15px;
color: $black;
background: none;
line-height: 19px;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 1px 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: To start I would pull out the icon — it may be part of a `<header>` but it is not semantically part of the _h6 heading_ itself `<i ... class="fa fa-info-circle">\</i\> <h6 className="font-weight-bold text-dark "\>` (etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the header, you would want to have it styled with [`flex` positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Something like this should work for you:

```
<h6 style={{ display: 'flex' alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <i style={{ color: '#D14444', fontSize: 23, marginRight: 6, }} class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
  This Dental Clinic is not accepting new patients at this time
</h6>
```